# Swift Vapor Sample Not compiling

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, vapor, build-settings, server-side-swift

I'm trying to get my feet wet with server side swift, and specifically Swift Vapor by trying the Ray Wenderlich HelloVapor tutorial.

Basically performed the following steps so far using (my swift -version on Apple command prompt is Apple Swift version 4.1.2)

Here are the steps I've followed to setup Vapor and try the sample.

1. On command prompt

[image]

2. Open browser to https://brew.sh for instructions to setup homebrew (Copy and paste the following in a command prompt on terminal)

[image]

3. Then run  the following commands to install vapor and the vapor sample app HelloVapor in folder vaporsample.

[image]

4. However when I try to build the run target I get the following compile errors:

[image]

It appears it cant find the modules. Or perhaps an incorrect version of swift (I am on Swift version 4.1.2 on my Mac). I'm confused and would like to seek the advise of the erudite crowd here.

Comment: The App module will be found after it is build. Firstly, `eval "$(curl -sL check.vapor.sh)"` as shown did not find Swift 4.1.  So, it would be informative to know the text output of `xcodebuild -version`, `swift --version`, and `which -a swift`.

Comment: $ swift --version

Comment: Apple Swift version 4.1.2 (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2)

Comment: $ which -a swift
/usr/bin/swift

Comment: $ xcodebuild -version

Comment: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Comment: You might do well to update to the current release Xcode 9.4.1 and say "yes" to the install the Xcode command tools on first launch. After an installation of the Xcode command lines tools you should no longer need to add Xcode to $PATH. In my case, I don't modify $PATH for any general (non-beta) Xcode release to get Vapor to build & run.

Comment: The update worked - thank you marc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a tip from @Marc (see comments) "You might do well to update to the current release Xcode 9.4.1 and say "yes" to the install the Xcode command tools on first launch. After an installation of the Xcode command lines tools you should no longer need to add Xcode to $PATH. In my case, I don't modify $PATH for any general (non-beta) Xcode release to get Vapor to build & run. – l --marc"

I followed Marc's tip and  the Vapor sample project buolt and ran with no issues in Xcode 9.4.1.

Thanks Marc.